# Can I run a message listener alongside an asynchronous looped task?

Tags: python, async-await, discord.py

I'm using discord.py to create a bot that looks for user updates on Anilist periodically. This task is run using discord.Client.loop.create_task(task), and it works as expected. However, when I try to use a message listener alongside this task, the bot does not respond. I've tested this code snippet before and it works, but alongside the task it does not work.

I've looked at the discord.py documentation and the documentation for create_task on asyncio.AbstractEventLoop, but there is no information about running a message listener concurrently with an AbstractEventLoop.

```py
client = discord.Client()

#message listener
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message == ".help":
        message.channel.send("test")

#background task
@client.event
@client.event
async def my_background_task():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    channel = client.get_channel(458644594905710595)
    while not client.is_closed():
        curr_time = int(time.time()-2)
        variables_pat = {
            'userId': 121769,
            'createdAt_greater': curr_time
        }

        variables_hani = {
            'userId': 320308,
            'createdAt_greater': curr_time

        }

        variables_phil = {
            'userId': 163795,
            'createdAt_greater': curr_time
        }

        variables_alan = {
            'userId': 121839,
            'createdAt_greater': curr_time
        }

        variables_ben = {
            'userId': 122953,
            'createdAt_greater': curr_time
        }

        variables_zen = {
            'userId': 382311,
            'createdAt_greater': curr_time
        }

        variables_me = {
            'userId': 323865,
            'createdAt_greater': curr_time
        }

        variables_min = {
            'userId': 169966,
            'createdAt_greater': curr_time
        }
        arr_vars = [variables_alan, variables_ben, variables_hani, variables_pat, variables_phil, variables_zen,
                    variables_me, variables_min]
        for variables in arr_vars:
            response = requests.post(url, json={'query': query, 'variables': variables})
            my_json = json.loads(response.content)
            if my_json["data"] is not None and my_json["data"]["Activity"] is not None:
                activity = my_json["data"]["Activity"]
                print(activity)
                if activity["progress"] is not None:
                    result_string = activity["user"]["name"] + " " + activity["status"] + " " + activity["progress"] + " of " + activity["media"]["title"]["romaji"]
                    result_embed = discord.Embed(
                        title="New Anilist Post",
                        color=discord.Color(0x039AFF),
                        description=result_string
                    )
                    await channel.send(embed=result_embed)
                else:
                    result_string = activity["user"]["name"] + " " + activity["status"] + " " + activity["media"]["title"]["romaji"]
                    result_embed = discord.Embed(
                        title="New Anilist Post",
                        color=discord.Color(0x039AFF),
                        description=result_string
                    )
                    await channel.send(embed=result_embed)

client.loop.create_task(my_background_task())
client.run(os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN"))
```

Comment: if it is totally not responsive it might be that your background task is not being sufficiently asynchronous (has blocking calls that are getting in the way).. since you have omited that code it's hard to tell exactly.

Comment: I added the (very sloppy) code

Comment: Use `aiohhtp` instead of `requests` so that your http calls are asynchronous.  It's already installed as a dependency of `discord.py`.  You can see an example here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#what-does-blocking-mean

Comment: yes. `requests.post` is blocking and only conditionally does it get to an `await` so in between there is no room for the other task to be handled. you would at least need a `await asyncio.sleep(N)` for there to be any chance of something else getting in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you wish, however you should be using the commands framework. Here is an example

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-')

bot.remove_command('help') # Remove the built-in help command since we have our own

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    # Once the bot has connected and is ready to go
    bot.my_current_task = my_task.start()

@tasks.loop(minutes=1) # Run every minute, takes hours, minutes, etc
async def my_task():
    # Put the code to be executed every loop here
    print("The loop hath run")

@my_task.before_loop # Before we start the loop make sure the bot is ready to go
async def before_my_task():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()

# Now the commands framework is nice, no longer do you need to handle commands within on_message
@bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Hello and welcome to my help command")

bot.run("TOKEN HERE")
```

Use your code in here, and then simply convert to using aiohttp
I hope this helps, any questions feel free to ask!